# papa parse memory leak error occure, parsing big files

Tags: jquery, ajax, parsing, csv, memory

I use papa parse for loading large files, maybe over 300MB.

Data is like this:

> 138,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 141,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 149,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 161,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 195,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 199,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 202,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 213,KOO,"0,2"
>
> 216,KOO,"2,0"
>
> .....

But loading memory leak error occur, IE and Chrome

[image]

Source here:

```js
if (scaffolds.length == -1) {
    console.log("1");
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "text",
        type: "post",
        url: "./data/" + currentParse + "_data.csv",
        success: function(result) {
            var geneData = CSVToArray(result);
            parseGene(Date.now(), scaffold, geneData, 0, "", [], [], 0);
        }
    });
}
else {
    console.log("2");
    var groupNameAndScaffoldName = scaffold.name.split("@");
    var groupName = groupNameAndScaffoldName[0];
    var scaffoldName = groupNameAndScaffoldName[1];

    var data = [];
    Papa.parse("../data/dataset/" + sampleFolderName + "/" + groupName + "/" + scaffoldName + "_data.csv",{
        download: true,
        delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
        newline: "",    // auto-detect
        header: false,
        dynamicTyping: false,
        preview: 0,
        encoding: "",
        worker: true,
        comments: false,
        step: function(result, handle) {
            if (result.data[0][0]) {
                data.push(result.data[0]);
            }
        },
        complete: function() {
            parseGene(Date.now(), scaffold, data, 0, "", [], [], 0);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        chunk: undefined,
        fastMode: false
    });
}
```

How can I debug?

Comment: If that screenshot is of the network tab, that's not a memory leak. That's just Papa Parse downloading the file in chunks as expected.

Comment: thanks. How can I use chunks this source. sorry, I'm beginner.

Answer (score 0):

@user3916421

If you want to use chunks you cannot use step. Then you can use chunk property to declare the function the same way you use step. Also if you want manage the chunk size, you can include a property chunkSize to the same config object.

```
Papa.parse("../data/dataset/" + sampleFolderName + "/" + groupName + "/" + scaffoldName + "_data.csv",{
        download: true,
        delimiter: "",  // auto-detect
        newline: "",    // auto-detect
        header: false,
        dynamicTyping: false,
        preview: 0,
        encoding: "",
        worker: true,
        comments: false,
        complete: function() {
            parseGene(Date.now(), scaffold, data, 0, "", [], [], 0);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        },
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        chunk: function(result, handle) {
            if (result.data[0][0]) {
                data.push(result.data[0]);
            }
        },
        chunkSize: 1024 * 1024 //in bytes
        fastMode: false
    });
```